# Create a message

Tags: list, dart

Below I would like to read the message 232
I did it but I have an error I know it's normal I need to do Message[0].en.
But is it possible to access of message 232 directly.
my problem is that I need this because I happen to delete a message in the middle then everything will be shifted

```
class Message {
      int messageId;
      String fr;
      String en;
    
      Message(this.messageId, this.fr, this.en );
    
      @override
      String toString() {
        return '{ ${this.messageId}, ${this.fr}, ${this.en} }';
      }
    
    }

 List<Message> msg = [];

 msg.add(Message(232, 'Bonjour', 'Hello' ));
 
 print(msg[232].en);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `firstWhere` to find in a list the element matching your request.

```
msg.firstWhere((message) => message.messageId == 232);
```

Comment: Hello FSuhen thank you too for your solution

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [Map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/Map-class.html) instead of a List:

```
Map<int, Message> msg = <int, Message>{};

msg[232] = Message(232, 'Bonjour', 'Hello');

print(msg[232].en);
```

This also makes deletion easier:

```
msg.remove(232);
```

Comment: Hello Kevin it's exactly that I want thank you for your help